# Macro declaration

Tags: objective-c, c

I have found this macro while digging in the source code of tweejump game.

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

For me cpp it is just alias to CGPointMake. Why is needed this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. cpp is less to type, and
2. someone could change the mapping, for example to wrap some debugging around the call

`#ifndef DEBUG`

`#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)`

`#else`

`#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) myassert2(((__X__) > 0),((__Y__) > 0), \`

             `CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__))`

`#endif`

Why would we want to do that? We can get the error for the line of source code which has a bug:

```
#define myassert2(xc1, c2, fun)  ((c1) && (c2)? fun((c1),(c2)): \
       fprintf(stderr, "Error in file %s, line %d, c1=%d c2=%d\", \
                        __FILE__, __LINE__, (c1), (c2))
```

BTW, in general it is safer for a macro to always wrap the arguments in parenthesis:

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake((__X__),(__Y__))
```

but as jamesdlin pointed out, in this case of a function call, it doesn't matter.

IMHO it is better to have a 'rule' that is safe, easy to explain and remember, and only vary away for strong reason, rather than have a more complex rule. After all, there are more interesting problems to solve (in my code) than whether or not to wrap a macro's arguments in parenthesis :-)

(I am especially mindful of simple rules due to a recent BBC Horizon program which offered evidence that humans can **not** successfully think about three things at once!-(

(HELP! What is the easy way to format C preprocessor source code like `#if ...`? the {} didn't work, back ticks didn't work, 4 leading spaces didn't work. They all eat some of the leading `#` characters)

Comment: What is a situation where the extra parentheses would matter when the macro arguments are being passed as arguments to a function?

Comment: Okay, to answer my own question, I claim they don't matter and that it's safe as it is.  https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE01-C.+Use+parentheses+within+macros+around+parameter+names#PRE01-C.Useparentheseswithinmacrosaroundparameternames-Exceptions seems to agree.

Comment: The only time it matters on a function call is C++. The ',' operation could change a two parameter call into a three parameter call, which might match an alternative signature. But the main point is macros parameters which are not in parenthesis can introduce very hard to spot bugs, so IMHO it is simpler to always add them. As you can see from my Q&D debug code, a typo, or a different precedence operator (lower than &&) could introduce a bug. People often take existing code, as the model, repeat those patterns, and add little pieces, so IMHO starting off safe is helpful for the future. Okay?

Comment: I don't think it matters in C++ either.  How would you pass a `,` through to the macro as part of the substitution?  If you did `ccp(1, 2, 3)`, it would try to match against a macro of 3 parameters.  If you did `ccp((1, 2), 3)`, then the first macro argument is already parenthesized.  I agree with recommending it as a safe practice to (almost) always parenthesize macro arguments, but I think it's a bit misleading to claim that it's actually any safer in this case.

Comment: @jamesdlin - I apologise for misleading you. You are correct, it doesn't matter in my example. I wonder what I am thinking of? My head is full of unappetising pinky-gray candyfloss. I still believe it is always better to use parenthesis because 1. it can never harm the code (though it does make it harder to read code, IMHO attempts to remove parenthesis for that reason can re-introduce a bug), 2. a very simple is easy to explain, 3. varying from a simple rule for a very strong reason is simpler to agree than varying from a complex rule. Doesn't change that I think I am incorrect on this.

Answer (score 3):

It is just that: an alias for `CGPointMake`. it is much easier to write 3 characters than 9.